# Setting up Gitblit as a service Windows Server 2003

Tags: git, service, repository, windows-server-2003, gitblit

as the title suggests, I need to set up Gitblit 1.2.1 as automatic service. If I run manually gitblit.cmd, everything works perfectly but I need this automatically. Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: I forgot... I used the following guide http://gitblit.googlecode.com/git-history/d9be12d95657435b0542861a64bb1fd781f14de8/setup.html

Comment: I forgot... I used the following guide [link](http://gitblit.googlecode.com/git-history/d9be12d95657435b0542861a64bb1fd781f14de8/setup.html)

and in installService.cmd I have only changed the parameter relating to architecture from amd64 to x86, because my operative system is windws server 2003 32 bit

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are opening ports in your firewall to allow for remote connections. If you specify

```
https://localhost
or
http://localhost
```

(depending on if you're using secure or not) does it work? If it works this way but not via IP Address/DNS then check your firewall settings. I had the same issue you're expressing until I checked if I could connect locally and when I could. It quickly narrowed down what was going on.